# Magento 1.9 show new products

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to show the latest products in Magento 1.9 on the home page. I am trying to show the newly added and new from date, but this not display together. I like to show together. 
New from date show with this widget

{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="new_products" products_count="4" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}

Last added show with this widget

{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="all_products" products_count="4" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}

I like to show together in one widget.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Open Magento admin panel

Go to **CMS>Pages>Home page**

Switch to the content tab

Insert the following code:

```
{{block  type="catalog/product_new" column_count="6"  products_count="12" name="home.catalog.product.new"  alias="product_homepage"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

[Reference link](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-display-new-products-on-the-home-page-block.html)

Comment: Thanks but not working.
Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on null in /catalog/product/list.phtml on line 39

Comment: <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count(); ?>
to

<?php $_collectionSize = count($_productCollection); ?>

Comment: Yes, I find this solution, but once you change it, it show the same error. :(